Firebase Function rewrite being processed as GET
After building a function and hosting (for a custom domain), I'm noticing that my POST request is getting processed as a GET in the logs.
This is my firebase.json file
{
    "hosting": {
        "public": "public",
        "ignore": ["firebase.json", "**/.*", "**/node_modules/**"],
        "rewrites": [
            {
                "source": "**",
                "function": "myFunc"
            }
        ]
    },
    "functions": [
        {
            "source": "functions",
            "codebase": "default",
            "ignore": ["node_modules", ".git", "firebase-debug.log", "firebase-debug.*.log", "*.local"]
        }
    ]
}


In my logging, I see only GET requests when hitting the rewritten URL, but I'm using postman and when I hit the URL directly (not through the rewrite), it works as expected. It also works as expected when using the local firebase:emulators.

It could be this, buy you tell very little about what you are actually doing: POST request getting converted to GET when URL rewriting is done in apache httpd

I discovered from my searching that https:// is required for POST requests.
